# Timers in Java EE / WebSphere

Tags: java, timer, ejb, websphere

I have an error in Websphere from our Web Service; it only shows up in WS installations with more than one servant.  It gives the following messages:

```
EJB Timer Service not available for EJB implementing the timed object interface

EJB Timer Service not available for TimedObject EJB {nameOfTimer}
```

We are developing with RAD; when we run within RAD, and when we run on WebSphere installations with only one servant, we don't see this error message.

It happens whether the timer is persistent:

```
TimerConfig timerConfig = new TimerConfig(name, true);
```

or non-persistent

```
TimerConfig timerConfig = new TimerConfig(name, false);
```

(we pass this to `createIntervalTimer()` or `createSingleActionTimer()`)

The class that creates the timer is annotated with @Startup and @Singleton; the TimerService is annotated with @Resource. The timeout() method is annotated with @Timeout.

What could be causing this error, only on installations with 2 servants?

I know SO is oriented towards specific answers to specific questions, but I don't know which of the hundreds of lines connected with this to post.  What issues are there with timers and multiple servants on WebSphere?

Comment: Can you add full stack trace? Which version and platform are you using? Try to delete timer database as described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21699234). If you use Derby and all your servants are on the same host, they cannot point to the same database (path).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  There is no stack trace, we just get trace statements from the server startup.  We have since learned that the Derby database used by default for the scheduler does not support multiple servants, and since we don't need persistent timers we are attempting to operate without them.  But the server still reports that the timer service is unavailable in this situation; we're still investigating.